# Null Pointer Exception in Richfaces Nested Accordion

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I'm using Richfaces 4.2.2 and I tried to implement nested accordion using the same. The Facelet code for the same is as follows :

```
<h:form id="accordForm">
    <rich:accordion switchType="client" activeItem="#{projectCreation.activeTab}">
        <c:forEach var="proj" items="#{projectCreation.projects}">
            <rich:accordionItem name="#{proj.description}">
                <f:facet name="header">#{proj.description}</f:facet>
                <h:form>
                    <rich:accordion switchType="client" activeItem="#{projectCreation.activeModuleTab}" rendered="#{proj.modules[0]!=null}">
                        <c:forEach var="mdle" items="#{proj.modules}">
                            <rich:accordionItem name="#{mdle.description}">
                                <f:facet name="header">#{mdle.description}</f:facet>
                                <t:dataList var="subMdle" value="#{mdle.subModules}" layout="unorderedList">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{subMdle.description}"></h:outputText>
                                </t:dataList>
                            </rich:accordionItem>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </rich:accordion>
                </h:form>
            </rich:accordionItem>
        </c:forEach>
    </rich:accordion>
</h:form>
```

However I'm getting `NullPointerException` and the error log is as follows:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.richfaces.component.AbstractAccordion.getActiveItem(AbstractAccordion.java:66)
    org.richfaces.component.AbstractTogglePanel.encodeBegin(AbstractTogglePanel.java:166)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1777)
    javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    org.richfaces.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:276)
    org.richfaces.renderkit.html.TogglePanelItemRenderer.doEncodeChildren(TogglePanelItemRenderer.java:136)
    org.richfaces.renderkit.html.AccordionItemRenderer.doEncodeChildren(AccordionItemRenderer.java:93)
    org.richfaces.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeChildren(RendererBase.java:157)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    org.richfaces.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:276)
    org.richfaces.renderkit.html.TogglePanelRenderer.doEncodeChildren(TogglePanelRenderer.java:127)
    org.richfaces.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeChildren(RendererBase.java:157)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:437)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124)
    javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:286)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:341)
    com.hcl.common.filter.MySessionFilter.doFilter(MySessionFilter.java:90)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
```

Does anyone knows why is it happening ?

Comment: It seams that `projectCreation.getActiveTab()` returns `null`. Can you check this in debugger?

Comment: Its not `null`, I've already checked that. Actually I've implemented simple accordion prior to implementing nested accordion and it was working fine.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://community.jboss.org/message/565139

Comment: @Christophe Roussy `c:forEach` works in a different way than `ui:repeat`. So you can't make that link appliable for this problem.

Comment: Are your `#{proj.description}` attributes being read properly? Check if they already have a value when you do the iteration.

Comment: @XtremeBiker Yes `#{proj.description}` are working properly and they have values.

Comment: And does it give you that problem if you comment internal `<h:form>` and all of its content?

Comment: @XtremeBiker It was already working that way, I mean that way it won't be nested accordion anymore.

Answer (score 0):

remove the activeItem attribute and set the id attribute to the rich:accordion. Worked for me. Good luck!

Comment: Good answer, but when you are helping someone who has provided code, always try to give them the fixed code sample, explain the changes, and why those are important to fixing their problem. That way the user has a sample to work off of next time and he knows what to do and why based on the sample and your answer.

Comment: @Diana Thanks for answering but I've just used some workaround for the problem. However as I think, activeItem attribute is necessary as I need to keep the check of selected accordion and I don't think id has anything to do with this as jsf implicity generates id attribute.